# JSF - Richfaces 3.3.3 rich datatable - Both sorting and filtering with two headers?

Tags: jsf, sorting, filter, datatable, richfaces

I'm trying to add a filter to the header of each column in an existing rich:datatable in JSF. I used the [Exadel](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/filteringFeature.jsf?tab=ex-usage) demo to add the filters, which worked out just fine, but it also removed the sort functionality from the upper header. I'd like to keep the sort function in the upper label header and filter on the second inputText header.

As a quick and dirty example, this is the basic structure:

```
<rich:dataTable id="thetable" value="#{stuff.list}" var="s">
    <f:facet name="header">
        <rich:columnGroup>
            <rich:column sortBy="#{s.field1}">
                <h:outputText="Field 1" />
            </rich:column>
        </rich:columnGroup>
    </f:facet>
    <rich:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:inputText value="#{stuffSorter.field1}">
                <a4j:support event="onkeyup" reRender="thetable" ignoreDupResponses="true"
                     requestDelay="700" onComplete"setCaretToEnd(event);" />
            </h:inputText>
        </f:facet>
    </rich:column>
</rich:dataTable>
```

There would be more columns, of course, and setCaretToEnd is just a Javascript function that keeps the caret at the end of the column filter. This is almost just right. I get two headers. The one at the top is the column label, the one just below is the filter, and the results are listed below that. I've built out the filtering class and it's working splendidly. However, I can't seem to find a way to get the sort function back into the topmost header. It does work if I put the "sortBy" field next to the filter box, but I'd much rather have it above, but it seems that the data being inserted in the filter column is preventing that.

Am I missing something here, or is this just not quite possible with a rich:dataTable? I'd be okay with the name + sort and then the filter on top of each other within the same header, but I'm not having luck with that, either. Trying to put both elements into the facet (outputText and inputText) never shows the outputText, even when wrapping them individually with an s:div. I'd use a bean for sorting, but strangely, the project I'm working in is using Richfaces 3.3.3 and lacks org.richfaces.component.SortOrder, although it has a number of other items within the richfaces-ui-3.3.3-final.jar.

Answer (score 1):

In Richfaces 3.3, header and filter facet are supported. The content which you put in the header facet will appear at the top. Filter code you can place inside the filter facet which will appear below header. Please check this questions :[Filter Facet is not working in Richface 4.3x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19353605/filter-facet-is-not-working-in-richface-4-3x), old format of richfaces 3.3 is shown there.

```
 <f:facet name="filter">
</f:facet>
```

Comment: I don't think it is supported in richfaces 3.3.3 Final [link]http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_column.html is not showing any facet named filter