# Filter Facet is not working in Richface 4.3x

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

In the Code below, You can observe two things:
1) Default sorting is getting utilized.
2) Image based custom filter is used.

**Problem I am facing** : When I click on filter image default sorting is getting triggered.
Need a way by which If I click on filter, default sorting doesn't get triggered. (This was achieved in Richface 3.3 by putting this custom filter in filter facet.)

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <rich:column sortBy="#{model.modVal}" label="Model Value"
    sortable="true" id="modelVal"  rendered="#{backingBean.renderMap['modVal']}">  
    <f:facet name="header">
    <h:outputText value="Model Value" />
        <h:graphicImage title="Filter"
            value="#{backingBean.dataModel.modValFilter }">
            <a4j:ajax event="click" render="filterCol"
        execute="@form"
        listener="#{backingBean.loadModalPanelData('modVal') }"
        oncomplete="#{rich:component('filterCol')}.show()">
        </a4j:ajax>
        </h:graphicImage>
        </f:facet>
<h:outputText value="#{model.modeVal}"
title="#{model.modelVal}" />
</rich:column>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use manual sorting, and place a click-able panel in your header for sorting, and another panel for filtering.

Answer (score 0):

The `filter` facet has been deprecated in favour of the `header` facet. So what you used to have in the `filter` facet, you can place in the header facet:

```
<f:facet name="header">
   <h:panelGrid>
      <h:outputText value="Model Value"/>
      <h:graphicImage title="Model Filter"/>
   </h:panelGrid>
</f:facet>
```

Comment: @kolossusIf I am placing the filter in the header facet then every time I click on the filter even sorting is getting invoked, as sorting is linked to the header.

Comment: @AmitBhati- that's probably my fault, they really shouldnt be in the same panel grid if you're doing more than just display. The example I've shown is applicable to display elements only. You should use a panel grouping that will separate input components

Comment: @kolossus-Thanks for your prompt response, tried panel grouping but no luck. As per my understanding,Sorting is by default linked to the header.So, as long as filter stays inside the header facet, it will trigger the sorting. Please let me know if you need some more details in order to solve this issue.

Comment: @AmitBhati - post your updated code. There really are just two options: Use the default table sorting (built into the column) or use the `header` facet. You can check the docs/demo to confirm

Comment: @kolossus-I have updated the original question. Posted the complete code of one of my rich:column of extended data table.Hope that helps.